# What phase are we in, today 22 January 2018? Still in Homestead?

Tags: ethereumj

What phase are we in in the Ethereum roadmap, today, 22 January 2018?  Are we in Homestead?

Answer (score 1):

As of block 4,370,000, we are in the first phase of Metropolis, called Byzantium. The second phase will be Constantinople, though there's no confirmed date for that yet.

See the official hard fork announcement, from last October, [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/10/12/byzantium-hf-announcement/).

> Metropolis is a planned Ethereum development phase that includes two
>   hard forks: Byzantium and Constantinople. Byzantium is occurring at
>   block number 4.37mil. Constantinople does not currently have a release
>   date, but is expected in 2018.